# About DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, import

The field name in the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet method is the first column in the range that we specified in the excel table as the field name. The Access application also needs to have the same field name for transferring data. I want to transfer it to the field name I have specified in the access application. For example, I would like to have Access application as companyName when the field name in excel is Company Name. How can I do that?

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "M1", selectFile, True, "C13:F168"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do this kind of thing.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "importTable", "C:\test\test.xlsx", ", True
```

OR

```
Public Sub autoFormat()
    wkbookPath = "C:\test.xlsx"
    Dim XL As Object
    Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With XL
        .Visible = False
        .displayalerts = False
        .Workbooks.Open wkbookPath
        .Columns("A:XFD").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
        .Quit
    End With
    Set XL = Nothing
End Sub
```